# Populate field by join query in entity jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Consider this usecase:

```
class Department {
   
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "dept_id")
   private Long deptId;
   
   @Column(name = "dept_name")
   private String deptName;

   // other heavy fields.
}
```

And,

```
class Student {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "dept_id")
   private Long deptId;
   
   // This I need to populate
   private String deptName; 

}
```

Here, deptId in Student Entity is foreign key to deptId(primary key) of Department entity.

What my requirement is I want to populate field deptName
inside Student Entity which is fetched from referenced Department entity.

I am already aware of solutions like fetching the Complete Department entity with:

```
@ManyToOne(fetchType.Eager)
@JoinColumn(//whatever)
private Department department;
```

WHICH I DONT WANT TO DO!

I just wanted single deptName field to be fetched. Also aware of @Formula and @JoinFormula. But under the impresssion that they are executed on entity level basis. I don't want to fetch for individual entity every time, instead I want something in bulk (so that number of calls to database can be reduced to one or two).

Coming to question how can I populate this single field efficiently?

TIA.

Comment: Let me know if you require more info for this question. TIA.

Comment: JPA is notoriously bad at having many custom queries. May I recommend a library that gives you more flexibility, such as jOOQ?

Comment: If you want partial data in a java object that doesn't line up to the table/entity structure - use a constructor query. Simply "select new package.Student(s.id, s.deptId, d.deptName) from Student s join s.department d". Note that what is returned is not managed entity instance data, but that seems like what you want, and constructor queries can return any java object

Comment: May I know, what amount of data are we talking about?
I mean how much data is there in your `Department` table?